# Grades from transfer university, impact on graduate admissions?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am wondering about what the impact of a poor grade that is taken as transfer credit would be.

I am taking a core EECS (Logic Gates) class at a different university for some transfer credit because I am working full-time this school year (as a co-op). Since my university required only a C for transfer, I was not planning to put much effort into the class because I'd be busy with work.

However, I recently found that some universities like Berkeley require transcripts from all schools attended. In this case, I'm sure that it'd look bad, but I am wondering how bad it would be?

Comment: Not to speak on what admissions would want, but a thought question: Would you prefer to have someone work for you that puts in the minimum level of effort or goes all in? Only you can decide your priorities and you can rationalize just about anything, but only you can reference your goals.

Answer (score 1):

For graduate admissions, transfer credit is treated the same way as regular credit.  Most universities will want all your undergraduate transcripts for graduate admissions.